# Using tween on class object, function definiton?

Tags: javascript, class, tween

I am trying to do scene effects opening and closing scenes. But something is wrong with my self and this values. It says not defined or not working. How can ı define these functions.

Ways I tried to define 
First way:

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.scene).to({alpha : 0}, 5000).call(menuOutCompleted(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp));
```

It is throwing "menuOutCompleted is not defined";

Second way:

```
   var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.scene).to({alpha : 0}, 5000).call(self.menuOutCompleted(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp));
```

It is not throwing any exception but does not do tween. It directly execute menuOutCompleted.

Third way:

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.scene).to({alpha : 0}, 5000).call(this.menuOutCompleted(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp));
```

It works like second way.

My js class

```
function CreditsScreen(SceneContainer)
{
var closePopUp_Button, background;
this.name = "CreditsScreen";
var self = this;
this.scene = new createjs.Container();
this.loadScreen = function()
{

    background = new createjs.Shape();
    background.graphics.beginBitmapFill(loader.getResult("coronaLogo")).drawRect(0,0,512,512);
    background.x = 200;
    background.y = 0;

    closePopUp_Button = new createjs.Sprite(buttonData, "exitIdle");
    closePopUp_Button.framerate = 30;
    closePopUp_Button.x = 400;
    closePopUp_Button.y = 22;

//  play.addEventListener("click", handleClickPlay);

    this.scene.alpha = 0;

    this.scene.addChild(background);
    this.scene.addChild(closePopUp_Button);
}


this.menuIn = function()
{
    console.log("menuIn   CreditsScreen" );
    stage.addChild(this.scene);
    //ptoblemetic part with self.menuInCompleted?
    var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.scene).to({y : 0, x : 0, alpha : 1}, 5000).call(self.menuInCompleted);

}


this.menuInCompleted = function()
{
    console.log("menuInCompleted   CreditsScreen" );
    self.addButtonEventListeners();

}

this.menuOut = function(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp)
{
    console.log("menuOut   CreditsScreen" );
    self.removeButtonEventListeners();
    if(isNextScreenPopUp == true)
    {
        self.menuOutCompleted(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp);
    }
    else
    {
    //problematic part with menuInCompleted?
        var tweenSplash = createjs.Tween.get(this.scene).to({alpha : 0}, 5000).call(menuOutCompleted(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp));
    }

}

this.menuOutCompleted = function(nextScreen,isNextScreenPopUp)
{
    console.log("menuOutCompleted  CreditsScreen" );
    if (isNextScreenPopUp)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        stage.removeChild(this.scene);
        this.scene.x = 0;
        this.scene.y = 0;
        this.scene.alpha = 1;
    }
    changeMenu(nextScreen, this.name, isNextScreenPopUp, true);

}
```

Comment: where is the var tween = .. set inside the CreditsScreen() ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem. Itis my call function. I send the parameters like menuoutcompleted(a,b) but in tween structure it must be (menuoutCompleted,[a,b]).

Now, It works :)